# Injective differentiable function between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ when $m< n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable function where $m< n$. Prove that $f$ is not injective.

I want to prove this using just techniques related with multivariate calculus and not very strong theorems from algebraic topology.

For example, if $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable we can do the following:

> Take $x_0$ a real number and defines $f_{x_0}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  as $f_{x_0}(y)=f(x,y)$ and choose a real $y_0$ such that 
>   $$\displaystyle\frac{df_{x_0}}{dy}(y_0)\not= 0$$
>   If $y_0$ does not exist then $f$ is not injective and we are done.
>
> Now we define $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ as $g(x,y)=(f(x,y), x)$. Then we have that $g$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ has as jacobian
>   $$\left|\begin{matrix}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}&{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\\{1}&{0}\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\not=0$$
>   and so we can use the inverse function theorem to find two open sets $U$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x_0,y_0)\in U$, $g(U)=V$ and there exist $h:V\rightarrow U$ differentiable which is the inverse function of $f$.
>
> Now we can conclude that $f$ is not $1-1$: Take any point $(x,y)\in U$ so $g(x,y)=(f(x,y),x)=(z,x)\in V $ since $V$ is open we can choose $x'\not= x$ such that $(z,x')\in V$. But $g(h(z,x'))=(z,x')$ and if $h(z,x')=(h_1(z,x'),h_2(z,x'))$ then 
>   $$g(h_1(z,x'),h_2(z,x'))=(f(h_1(z,x'),h_2(z,x'),h_1(z,x'))=(z,x')$$
>   and so $f(x,y)=f(x',h_2(z,x'))$. This prove that $f$ is not injective in this case.

Can I generalize this argument? Any hint?

Comment: You need to fix the title too.

Comment: I've changed the statement. And I prove in that way in an special case, but I want to generalize it. Thats what I'm asking.

Comment: @RobArthan Why does the inverse function theorem imply that the Jacobian must be invertible? An injective differentiable function does not need to have invertible Jacobian.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I suspect that you are actually trying to prove invariance of domain, more or less. And that requires a certain amount of topology: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/ I am curious, nonetheless.

Comment: BTW: This link has an answer to your problem, if you consider $f \in C^1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851644/non-existence-of-c1-injective-mapping-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr2

Comment: Actually, I think Giuseppe is right. I was forgetting that the inverse function theorem isn't an "iff". Apologies!